# Sorting a list according to natural ordering of elements

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want descending sort type of code below:

This is ascending sort:

```
public static <T extends Vm> void sortByCpuUtilization(List<T> vmList) {
    Collections.sort(vmList, new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T a, T b) throws ClassCastException {
            Double aUtilization = a.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            Double bUtilization = b.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            return bUtilization.compareTo(aUtilization);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare a with b instead:

```
public static <T extends Vm> void sortByCpuUtilization(List<T> vmList) {
    Collections.sort(vmList, new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T a, T b) throws ClassCastException {
            Double aUtilization = a.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            Double bUtilization = b.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            return aUtilization.compareTo(bUtilization);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. First, you could just implement a reverse comparator:

```
public static <T extends Vm> void sortByCpuUtilizationDesc(List<T> vmList) {
    Collections.sort(vmList, new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T a, T b) throws ClassCastException {
            Double aUtilization = a.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            Double bUtilization = b.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            return aUtilization.compareTo(bUtilization); // Note this is reversed
        }
    });
}
```

But much more elegantly, you could use [`Collections.reverseOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder(java.util.Comparator)):

```
public static <T extends Vm> void sortByCpuUtilizationDesc(List<T> vmList) {
    // Same comparator as before, should be extracted to a named class.
    Collections.sort(vmList, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T a, T b) throws ClassCastException {
            Double aUtilization = a.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            Double bUtilization = b.getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(CloudSim.clock());
            return aUtilization.compareTo(bUtilization); // Note this is reversed
        }
    }));
}
```